# Check if FTP Server supports MLSD

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am using apache.commons.net.FTPClient to get some files from customers but I found that there is a ftpserver that doesn't process the command list as it should because it always return the current directory instead of the one that I indicate.

I found out that mlistFile (MLSD) works great on that machine!

My question is: 
Is there any way to find out with apache.commons.net if there I should use the MLDS or LIST commnad?

Any flag or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: You could just send the mlsd command and check the reply code. If you get a 202 code try list instead. (see codes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes)

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I found (maybe too late?): you can invoke the function listHelp() on a FTPClient object to get the commands recognized by the remote server. You get an output such as

```
214-The following commands are recognized.
 ABOR ACCT ALLO APPE CDUP CWD  DELE EPRT EPSV FEAT HELP LIST MDTM MKD
 MODE NLST NOOP OPTS PASS PASV PORT PWD  QUIT REIN REST RETR RMD  RNFR
 RNTO SITE SIZE SMNT STAT STOR STOU STRU SYST TYPE USER XCUP XCWD XMKD
 XPWD XRMD
```

You just have to check if MLSD is in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "FEAT" command.
It shows commands you can use.

Comment: Tried in some server, FEAT only show MLST, but HELP show both MLST and MLSD.

Comment: I think HELP will tell you what your client supports. FEAT will give what the server supports.